# App is crashing when I run it

Tags: java, android

I do not get any errors but when I run the app it crashes:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageButton Nr1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ImageButton1);
    public void machwas(View v) {
        Nr1.setImageResource(R.drawable.x);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: if the app is crashing you are getting for sure an error message, take a look in the LogCat....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This here is wrong:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageButton Nr1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ImageButton1);
```

because `findViewById()` should be called INSIDE the `onCreate` method, the reason is that after that are layouts inflated and you are ready to get the views and initialize the widgets...

so what you are doing is initializing the ImageButton  wrongly, probably will be null after that line and then this here

```
public  void machwas(View v){
        Nr1.setImageResource(R.drawable.x);
    }
```

is going to explode with a NullPointer Exception...

but this is only an inference because you dont post the LogCat...

For more info please take a look to the Activity lifeCycle and the [Official Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to call findViewById after view created.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageButton Nr1 ;


public  void machwas(View v){
    Nr1.setImageResource(R.drawable.x);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Nr1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ImageButton1);
    machwas(0);
}
}
```

Comment: findViewById must be called after view is set on that activity. Correct it.

Answer (score 1):

`findViewById()` searches the view that is set by `setContentView()`. In your code `findViewById()` is called before `onCreate()` so there's no view set yet and due to that all finds will fail and you will always get `null` there.

BTW: consider using helpers like ButterKnife